# TFS API Get Deletes file - Different behavior after update to new version (from 14xx to 16xx)

Tags: c#, .net, api, tfs, azure-devops

I've upgraded the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll** from version **14 (.98.25331.0)** to **16 (.149.28804.2)** and noticed a strange behavior. I'm not sure if it's expected or a bug.

Consider this situation:

The user has a server-workspace which is mapped to a local path.

The user does a **check-out** on a file, realizes that it wasn't intentional and performs an **undo**. He then compares the file to another file (this happens by creating a **new workfolder on appdata**, mapping it and getting the file to that location). This previously worked fine, the initial file on the local path **didn't get touched** and remained there.

After upgrading to version 16(.149.28804.2), the 'old' file on the local folder **will be deleted right after getting** the file to the **new, temporary path**.

Is that intended or is that a bug?

I'm not sure if code helps in this case, I'll provide it anyway

```
workSpace.Undo(undoFiles, RecursionType.OneLevel, false);
```

[Related MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb139443(v=vs.120)) for undo.

```
workSpace.Get(getFiles, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.OneLevel, GetOptions.None);
```

[Related MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb139316(v=vs.120)) for get.

Any ideas?

---

edit:

After some investigation it seems like it's intended. Using the `tf.exe` of the 2017 VS, the line `replacing ... (moved from xx)`  appears. Seems like it's meant to be like that. Doesn't really help me, though.

---

Edit 2:

I've found the cause of the problem (or rather expected behavior).
In the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll** there's this piece of code

```
if (asyncGetFileState.m_existingLocalExists && asyncGetFileState.m_action.CurrentLocalItem != null && !FileSpec.Equals(asyncGetFileState.m_action.CurrentLocalItem, asyncGetFileState.m_action.TargetLocalItem))
{   
    asyncGetFileState.m_client.DeleteSource(asyncGetFileState.m_action, asyncGetFileState.m_existingLocalAttrs);
}
```

Note the properties `CurrentLocalItem` and `TargetLocalItem`.
Because of the fact that `CurrentLocalItem` still **refers to the original location** and `TargetLocalItem` **refers to the temp-folder**, the file in the original Location is being deleted. That happens with **both** versions, it just seems like we've never noticed it with the previous version.

However, there might be a way to update the cache so that `CurrentLocalItem` also refers to the same location `TargetLocalItem` is referring to, so that my original file doesn't deleted. I'll look into that soon.

Comment: Sorry, not totally get your point, especially about the temporary path. Could you give detail steps to reproduce your issue or a related screenshot? Your original issue is talking about client api to undo/get files, but your update is referring `tf.exe`.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I've used the ```tf.exe``` just to verify whether it's happening just in my code if it's happening with the ```tf.exe``` as well - which is the case. I also found the cause of the problem, see the update in my post. There's not enough space in the comment for the whole description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I'll put my final edit as an answer.

I've found the cause of the problem (or rather expected behavior).
In the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll** there's this piece of code

```
if (asyncGetFileState.m_existingLocalExists && asyncGetFileState.m_action.CurrentLocalItem != null && !FileSpec.Equals(asyncGetFileState.m_action.CurrentLocalItem, asyncGetFileState.m_action.TargetLocalItem))
{   
    asyncGetFileState.m_client.DeleteSource(asyncGetFileState.m_action, asyncGetFileState.m_existingLocalAttrs);
}
```

Note the properties `CurrentLocalItem` and `TargetLocalItem`.
Because of the fact that `CurrentLocalItem` still **refers to the original location** and `TargetLocalItem` **refers to the temp-folder**, the file in the original Location is being deleted. That happens with **both** versions, it just seems like we've never noticed it with the previous version.

A working solution is to rename the original file and restore the name after getting it to the temp folder.

However, there might be a way to update the cache so that `CurrentLocalItem` also refers to the same location `TargetLocalItem` is referring to, so that my original file doesn't deleted. I'll look into that and update my answer if I can find a better solution.